# Issue with Google Drive API and WordPress/Elementor - Links to Files Result in “Page Not Found”

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-drive-api, elementor

I’m trying to use the Google Drive API to list files from a specific folder on my WordPress website built with Elementor. The goal is to allow users to view these documents directly from the website. I’ve written JavaScript code that uses the Google Drive API to fetch the file information and generate links for each file.

I’m wondering if there might be a conflict with WordPress or Elementor that’s causing this issue. Has anyone else experienced this problem or have any suggestions on how to fix it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    <style>
        /* Tilføj en CSS-regel for at gøre links sorte */
        #drive-folder a {
            color: black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="drive-folder"></div>
    <script>
        // Opret en funktion til at indlæse Google Drive-mappen
        function loadDriveFolder() {
            gapi.load('client', function () {
                gapi.client.init({
                    apiKey: 'My API is typed here normally', // Erstatt med din API-nøgle
                    discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest'],
                }).then(function () {
                    // Hent indholdet af mappen ved hjælp af Drive API
                    gapi.client.drive.files.list({
                        q: "'Folder ID here normallt' in parents", // Erstatt 'MAPPENS_ID' med mappens ID
                    }).then(function (response) {
                        var fileList = response.result.files;
                        var folderContent = '<ul>';
                        fileList.forEach(function (file) {
                            var fileLink = '<a href="' + file.webViewLink + '" target="_blank">' + file.name + '</a>';
                            folderContent += '<li>' + fileLink + '</li>';  // Brug fileLink i stedet for file.name
                        });
                        folderContent += '</ul>';
                        document.getElementById('drive-folder').innerHTML = folderContent;
                    }, function (error) {
                        console.error('Fejl ved hentning af Google Drive-mappen: ' + error.message);
                    });
                });
            });
        }

        // Kald funktionen til at indlæse mappen, når siden indlæses
        loadDriveFolder();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I’ve checked the sharing permissions for the files and the folder in Google Drive, and they are all publicly accessible. I’ve also verified that my API key is correct and has the necessary permissions.